# What happens when we run out of names

Tags: account-name

Will we have a proposal to increase the account name length as we get closer to running out of names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 26 letters and 5 numbers available for making standard EOS names, meaning there are [image: 31^12] = 787662783788549761 possible names available. And that excludes all the non-standard names that are currently being bid on.

Each EOS account currently costs about 0.7 EOS in RAM to create.

We will not run out of names.